# fontawesome icon not showing on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I seem to be having an issue displaying the fontawesome icon in my browser. It does show in inspect, but not on my website itself.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

```
import React, { Fragment, useState} from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "../styles/common/Navbar.css";


const Navbar = () => {
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

    return (
      <Fragment>
          <nav>
              <a href="/">
              <h1>AnRa<span>Caribbean</span></h1>
              </a>
              <div className={showMenu ? "menu mobile-menu" : "menu"}>
                  <ul>
                      <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                      <li><NavLink to="/PropertiesForSale">Buy a Property</NavLink></li>
                      <li><NavLink to="/PropertiesForRent">Rent a Property</NavLink></li>
                      <li><NavLink to="/About">About</NavLink></li>
                      <li><NavLink to="/Contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                  </ul>
                  <button className="btn">
                      <NavLink to="#">Add Property</NavLink>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <i className="fa fa-solid fa-bars" onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}></i>

          </nav>
      </Fragment>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

[Web view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHa49.png)

How I have it in css from max-width screen.

```
.fa-bars{
    display: flex;
    color: gold;
}
```

Thank you in advance

1. downloaded

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

Still nothing.

2. tried deleting nodemodules.
3. restarted the application.

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Font Awesome docs, it should be used like the following:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const App = () => {
   return (<div><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} /></div>)
}

export default App
```

Comment: no still not showing :( this removed my whole navbar And a buch of errors in the console

Comment: This is just an example of how it works. You should not copy the whole thing in your app. You just need 2 imports of FontAwesomeIcon and the icon you want to use at the top. Then wherever you want to use the icon, you need to use the <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} /> tag. Instead of "faCoffee" you should put the name of the icon you tend to use.

Comment: Yes I did but was still missing one npm install. Works now!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow all the steps from the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/#_3-add-the-react-component)?
The third step is to add the `FontAwesomeIcon` component and use it the following way:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
```

Check the [docs](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#alternative-ways-to-add-icons) about how to use icons

PS: do not forget to import the component and the icon:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

Comment: omg i really thought it I had done it all. But it finally worked!! thank you so much! the 
` <i className="fa fa-solid fa-bars" onClick={() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)}></i>`

Still doesn't work but the one you just send did